# QtCreator and MySQL - how to establish connection?

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, qt-creator

This question was asked many times on SO, but with new framework for QT (5.2), and MySQL (<5),  all answers are outdated, also QT docs are astonishingly useless about this topic (astonishingly, because usually QT docs are very helpfull).

I am trying to connect to mysql database, unfortunately (or not) I am used to MinGW with Windows, and don't want to switch to Linux or Visual which would (probably) be the fastest way to workaround this.

Behaviour:
After I am using this:

```
QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL")
```

I get:

```
QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QMYSQL QMYSQL3 QODBC QODBC3 QPSQL QPSQL7
"Driver not loaded Driver not loaded"
```

I was trying to use old QT docs (from 5.1 QT) to build mysql library for qt, but steps from this failed. I was not confused about failure - those steps were from old QT from WinXp, and also those steps does not took into consideration that MySQL no longer have simple connector libs - they had split those into several languages, and also names and paths had changed.

Here comes my question. Does anyone know proper way to build MySQL connector for new QT ?

Comment: afaik its like described here http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/sql-driver.html#qmysql . used mysql about a year ago and after building the plugin all worked as expected

Comment: I had already seen this, building process on this site for MySQL extension is only described for Visual compiler (not MinGW). As I already wrote in my question, there are building steps for MinGW, but with older documentation, and those steps are outdated, not working.